# Upgrade Java version in Java 1.8 project to Java 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, java-17

I am planning to upgrade the java version in my project from 1.8 to 17.0.4.1, Hence I wanted to know which all component may break after upgradation. And which version of these component are compatible with Java 17. Anyone who  are using java 17 or upgraded to java 17 may share your findings.

Comment: do yourself a favor, don't take that huge a step. first upgrade to a lower version, it 'll be less changes. Step by step upgrade until you are at Java 17

Comment: How are *we* supposed to know which components of *your* software may break?

Comment: Yes  share which components you are using. How will we be able to tell you

Comment: Since each project is unique with its flow and dependencies the best way is to simply upgrade it to JDK17 and follow the exceptions which will lead you to which dependencies need to be updated in order to run on JDK17.

Comment: read the Release Notes and Migration Guide that come with each Java version: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/)

Answer (score 0):

just create a dummy project of spring.io with java 17 and add the dependencies you want to add and download it import it and then look at the XML file you will get all compatible dependencies

for reference look this https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/its-time-to-move-your-applications-to-java-17-heres-why-and-heres-how